# On handleChange, setState and the map array with new items depending on the setedState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I'm trying to fill up new array with older array dynimcally, depending on the id that is inside of the settedState, here is the code.
"I can't make it to work"

```
    handleChange: function (e) {
    var self = this;
    this.setState({ targetid: e.target.value });
    var newArr = [];
    newArr = this.state.data.filter(function(item){
        return item.id === self.state.targetid;
    }).map(function (item) {
        return item;
    })

    this.setState({targetArr : newArr})
}
```

I do not really know how to do that, If someone need more explanations, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is not a synchronous function, you try to read in state before it was written. You can access `targetid` without setting it in the state. Try this code instead :

```
handleChange: function (e) {
  var targetid = e.target.value;

  var newArr = this.state.data.filter(function(item){
    return item.id === targetid;
  });

  this.setState({
    targetArr: newArr,
    targetid: targetid
  });
}
```

Comment: You are right, it is much better to do it this way. Tho It doesn't add to the state array, I guess it is cause target is is a string and can't compare to the  int id?

Comment: If you want to be sure you can put a breakpoint on your browser dev tool to see the type of item.id, or `console.log(typeof item.id)`, if it's a number you have to cast targetid. `var targetid  = Number(e.target.value);`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `setState` method, react will again render the component for the changes, so its not a good idea to use multiple `setState` in any event. Always try to use `setState` at the end of all calculation. In this case, you are facing issue because of this only, remove the first setState and directly use the e.target.value to filter out the element, then in the last use `setState`, it will work. Try this:

```
_handleChange: function (e) {
     let targetId = e.target.value;

     let newArr = this.state.data.filter((item)=>{
           return item.id === targetId;
     });

     this.setState({
        targetArr: newArr,
        targetid: targetId
     });
}
```